# Apple Pencil pen color is darker than the color given to PKInkingTool

Tags: swift, ipad, pencilkit

I've got the bare minimum apple pencil setup: a `PKCanvasView` named 'drawingView' given an inking tool as follows (to set the starting pen color):

```
let penColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
drawingView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: penColor, width: 15)
```

However, when I use the pen, it is extremely dark (I've tried this with several colors besides `.white`). Is this a glitch interal to PencilKit that others are experiencing, or am I missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just realized the issue. Figure I might as well leave it up in case it proves useful to someone. `PKCanvasView` darkens its pen colors when the device is in dark mode. To override that, I set the following property of `drawingView` (my `PKCanvasView`):

```
drawingView.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the best answer